# Move semantics: invalid conversion from `type&&` to `type`. Templates: passing unknown arguments to overloaded functions

Tags: c++, move-semantics, variadic-functions

The story is the following: there is a fixed-type memory pool `Pool` which stores the elements of some type `T`. Both issues listed in the title were encountered while making the `alloc()` function which constructs and adds a new element into the pool:

```
template <class T, size_t qty, class Alloc = allocator<T>>
class Pool {
    array <T*, qty> cells; // Pointers to pre-allocated memory
    ...
public:
    T& alloc (...) {   // [2] It is unknown what parameters T's constructor may take
        T&& tmp (...); // [2] But I need them to be passed as they are
        size_t cellNo = findEmptyCell(); // Returns the number of the cell
        *cells[cellNo] = tmp; // Placing the new object into the pool
                              // [1] "invalid conversion from 'int&& (*)(...)' to 'int'" when T is int
        isEmpty[cellNo] = false; // Marking the cell as occupied
        return *cells[cellNo];
    }
}
```

So, 1) how to avoid unnecessary object copying in this case?
And 2) is there a way to pass arbitrary arguments to the constructor?

Comment: `T&& tmp (...);` This is declaring a function. I'm guessing you meant something else and used the wrong syntax. Also, unless I'm mistaken, your memory pool isn't full of pre-constructed objects, so `*cells[cellNo] = tmp` should be UB whenever the type isn't POD. Just use placement new.

Comment: Yes, I supposed passing the arguments of `alloc()` to `T()`, thanks for the error [1] explanation. But why should `*cells[cellNo] = tmp` generate UB? `cells` point to pre-allocated memory, so this should just use it. Or do you mean that it is a call for `operator=` which is not defined for the rubbish originally located at `*cells[cellNo]`?

Comment: It will call `operator=`. If you allocated memory already and constructed an object there, it'll work as expected. If the object isn't constructed and it's not POD, then that will cause UB. And of course if you didn't allocate memory then it will detonate spectacularly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for "perfect forwarding" with a variadic function template:

```
template <class... Args>
T& alloc(Args&&... args) { 
    size_t cellNo = findEmptyCell();
    *cells[cellNo] = T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    isEmpty[cellNo] = false;
    return *cells[cellNo];
}
```

This will take any number of arguments, and forward them (copy for lvalues, move for rvalues) into the `T` constructor. That temporary object will then be move-assigned into `*cells[cellNo]`.

Comment: Is there any difference between `*cells[cellNo] = T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);` and `new (cells[cellNo]) T(forward<Args>(args)...);` for this case?

Comment: @Alex Yes - is there an old object for that pointer? If so, the assignment will do the right thing but the placement new won't destruct the old one. If no old object, then assignment is wrong.